# Index of multiple max values in array

Tags: c#, .net

I have an array of for example

```
int[] array = new int[] {1, 3, 2, 3};
```

and problem is with getting index of **multiple max values** from an array.

Comment: Do you mean you want all of the indexes of every instance of a unique number? Can you edit to show us your attempt so far?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First get the max:

```
int max = array.Max();
```

Now get the indices of the elements that have that value:

```
var indices = array.Select((x, i) => new { Index = i, Value = x })
    .Where(x => x.Value == max)
    .Select(x => x.Index);
```

Comment: Given the nature of the question, the OP probably doesn't even know what LINQ is nor they can use it. I would have waited until we got more information before answering something like this

Answer (score 2):

Here's how you can do that in one loop.

```
var indices = new List<int>();
int max = int.MinValue;
for(int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
{
    if(array[i] > max)
    {
        max = array[i];
        indices.Clear();
    }

    if(array[i] == max)
    {
        indices.Add(i);
    }
}
```

Basically you keep track of the max and a list of indices.  When you see a value greater than the max you set it to max and clear the list since any indices in there are no longer pointing at the max.  Then just check if the value equals the max and add the index to the list if it does.

Answer (score 1):

With an extention method given that you already have the maxValue you are looking for:

```
public static IEnumerable<int> AllIndexesOf(this List<T> list, T searchValue)
{
    int minIndex = list.IndexOf(searchValue);
    while (minIndex != -1)
    {
        yield return minIndex;
        minIndex = list.IndexOf(searchValue, minIndex + 1);
    }
}
```

You can have :

```
int[] array = new int[] {1, 3, 2, 3};
int maxValue = array.Max(); 
int[] indexesOfMax = array.AllIndexesOf(maxValue).ToArray();
```

Comment: `IEnumerable<T>` does not contain a definition for `IndexOf`. Also you need to change your methods signature to `AllIndexesOf<T>(…)` to correctly work. Besides that I really like the approach of yield returning all the values.

Comment: @FelixB., original answer was on List<T> that as the index of. I changed it with out checking compatibility. variable is still name list.

Answer (score 1):

Linq approach

```
int[] array = new int[] { 1, 3, 2, 3 };

int[] result = array.Select((x, i) => new { index = i, value = x })
                    .GroupBy(x => x.value)
                    .OrderByDescending(x => x.Key)
                    .First()
                    .Select(x => x.index)
                    .ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

As a counter to @HimBromBeere's answer

We can use a dictionary for every unique number and then a list of integers for every index it showed up.

```
var intArray = new int[5];
var dictionary = new Dictionary<int, List<int>>();
for (int i = 0; i < intArray.Length; i++)
{
    var num = intArray[i];
    if (!dictionary.ContainsKey(num))
     {
        dictionary.Add(num, new List<int>());
     }

     dictionary[num].Add(i);
}

var max = dictionary.Keys.Max();
return dictionary[max];
```

This has less overall operations but is a bit more terse.

Comment: You are right, I need to explicitly iterate over the value of the keys

Comment: Yes, I fixed the case and fixed logic behind accessing the value of max. Apologies for the lax attention paid to that.

Comment: The main problem with this is that it's doing way more than is needed.  I'd only create a dictionary like that if I actually needed to get the indexes for different values, not just the max.

Comment: What if the list is a billion elements? In the above linq statements we would iterate the entire collection multiple times. The worst case here is iterating the list once, as well as iterating the number of unique numbers. I agree it's very terse but it's not objectively worse -- Edit, I didn't even see your answer when I replied to this. Much more succinct! Apologies for thinking you replied with the linq answer

Answer (score 0):

Using `yield return` and looping through the array you can do this:

```cs
using Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public static class IEnumerableExtensions
{
    // Extension method for IEnumerable
    public static IEnumerable<int> AllIndexesOf<T>(this IEnumerable<T> list, T searchValue)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < list.Count(); i++)
        {
            if (list.ElementAt(i) == searchValue)
            {
                yield return i;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then find the max value in the array using LINQ and call the method:

```cs
using Linq; // include this at the top of your file, if not already present.

// ...

int[] array = new int[] {1, 3, 2, 3};

IEnumerable<int> matchingIndexes = array.AllIndexesOf(array.Max());

// Convert to array if you need one
int[] matchingIndexesArr = matchingIndexes.ToArray();
```

You can find more information about extension methods [in the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/extension-methods).

Comment: @fubo Thanks for the note, I changed the code to include the check if value at `i` is the same as `searchValue`

Comment: `ElementAt` is **very** in-performant when using in a loop, as it iterates the complete collection again and again.

Comment: Well, I made a similar error that you noticed. We trend to forget that `IEnumerable` is just a brunch of element that are waiting to be iterate in lazy. It has no understanding of index. When you need touse index , you need datastructure that support the concept like List or Collection or their respective inferface.